# How to call a container component from within contained component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

my landing page component declares in it a header component like so

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="intro-section">
        <div class="background">
            //some stuff
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <app-page-header></app-page-header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text header mt-3">
                    Hello World
                </div>                
                <div class="col-12 text-center mt-4 mb-4">
                    <button class="btn know-more-btn text" (click)="scroll(subscriptions)">Tell me More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div #subscriptions></div>
    <div id="others" class="otherSection">
        //other stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

the scroll function in `landing-page.component.ts` is

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});
  }
```

I've also tried this

```
scrolling() {         
    (document.getElementById('others')).scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});
  }
```

I want to have a button in my `app-page-header` component that triggers or perform the same action an `"scroll(subscriptions)"` i.e in the landing page scroll to `subscriptions`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can add an output binding to `app-page-header` and bind it to `scroll(subscriptions)` in this page.

Comment: @31piy Thanks the output worked and the nested element invokes the scroll function successfully. Unfortunately the actual scroll is not happening. but when invoking the scroll function from the button located directly in the landing page (Tell me More)  it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Create an EventEmitter inside you app-page-header like

```
@Output() onButtonClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

The button in your app-page-header will emit the action to the parent component like:

```
buttonClicked() {
    onButtonClicked.emit();
}
```

On your landing page add this to call the scroll function whenever the event is emitted.

```
<app-page-header (onButtonClicked)="scroll(subscriptions)"></app-page-header>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The nested element does invoke the scroll function but the actual scroll is not happening -- whereas from a button set in the landing page calling the same exact scroll function it works fine. any ideas?

Comment: Can you share you html and ts file?

Comment: I've edited my question and added the relevant code in it, thanks

Comment: change the scroll(subscriptions) to scroll()
You dont need to give a parameter.
Change the function to the following:
scroll() {
(document.getElementById('subscriptions')).scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});
}

Comment: I've tried this, it behaves the same from the main page button it works but from the nested component it doesn't

Comment: @KukulaMula, [here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-into-view-from-child-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) showing it working with the implementation described in this answer (on Chrome desktop, anyway). If your non-working implementation is different, it would be helpful if you could maybe fork this StackBlitz and configure it to match your scenario so others can see the failure in action and help debug it more efficiently.

Comment: @MikeJ thanks for the StackBlitz, it helped figure out my problem using the <a> and having href="#".